# Is it a good idea to use crontab and touch to prevent old files from purging on network filesystem?

Tags: linux, bash, touch, cron, purge

I have an account on remote network file system and files older that 12 weeks are purged. I was wondering if it is a good idea to touch every file once in a week using crontab.

Some files on that filesystem are being updated by different numerical programs running on the cluster. Would there be any conflict if a file is being updated and was touched at the same time?

This is what I am planning to do:

**crontab file**

```
0 0 * * 0 find /globle/scratch/sd/pratik -exec touch { } \;
```

Comment: I find it very difficult to believe that they expect every file to be modified frequently. They probably check the access time, not modification time.

Comment: So use `touch -a` to update the access time.

Comment: access time is set to mod time or creation time by most admins to save cpu time.

Comment: You might talk to the system administrator about why old files are purged, why you need to keep older files, and how to preserve them.